# jQuery script that replaces every dom element with a custom tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script that queries all the dom elements from a div and replaces them with some custom markup - the script should work... but obviously it doesn't and I have no idea why.

Here is the js:

```
var data = {
            SPAN: function(content) {
                return '|span|' + content + '|span|'
            },
            DIV: function(content) {
                return '|div|' + content + '|div|'
            },
            P: function(content) {
                return '|p|' + content + '|p|'
            },
            H2: function(content) {
                return '|h2|' + content + '|h2|'
            },
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Iterate through each element of the dom.
            $('#result *').each(function () {
                var type = $(this)[0].tagName;

                var content = $(this).html();

                if (data[type]) var result = data[type](content);

                if (result) $(this).replaceWith(result);
            });

            console.log($('#result').html())
        });
```

This is the html I target:

```
<div id="result">
        <div id="wrap">
            <div class="about">
                <p>Hello, I am a web dev, <span class="italicStyle">the best!</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="evenMore">
                <h2>Yes, I am a big heading 2.</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I should be seeing every div, span, p replaced accordingly... why doesn't it work?

The code replaces only the first dom elm... here is the result:

```
|div|
Hello, I am a web dev, the best!

Yes, I am a big heading 2.

|div|
```

Comment: This occurs because you replace the contents of the HTML every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you start from the bottom to the top and rewrite the entire HTML. You see, you first iteration is on the `div` and you do `$(this).replaceWith(result)`.

This means you are changing all of its children, so the second `div` in the iterations **no longer exists in the first one**.

You can achieve what you want by reverse looping. It means starting from the last element:

```
var $elements = $('#result *');
for(var i = $elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    (function() {
        var type = $(this)[0].tagName;

        var content = $(this).html();

        if (data[type]) var result = data[type](content);

        if (result) $(this).replaceWith(result);
    }).call($elements[i]);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nHjCE/

Comment: Ty Karl, wow, this is amazing:) I will approve your question... but can I leave it open for a while, I may have some additional questions.. would it be ok?

Comment: @DanyD we generally don't offer long period of support. If your additional question are caused by another thing than this current answer, it may be better to ask another question. With a link to this one for context information.

Comment: You can, however, comment on this answer if you open another ticket. You may ask the question here, but depending on the difficulty of the task, i may say *"Open an other question"* or *"i don't have time for this"*